# How do I return the result of my fetch call using combine?

Tags: swift, combine

I am new to combine and struggling to understand how I can return the result of my fetch pins.

I can set the result as `@Published` but I want to just be able to call the fetch method and await the result or error.

```
class PinService: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    private var session: Session
    private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init(session: Session) {
        self.session = session
        super.init()
    }
    
    func fetchPins (categories: Set<CategoryModel>, coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D)  {
        _fetchPins(categories: categories, coordinates: coordinates)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                switch completion {
                case .failure:
                    print("fetchPins() error")
                case .finished:
                    print("fetchPins() complete")
                }
            }, receiveValue: { pins in
                /*
                    What to do here?
                 
                    I can add a @Published var pins: [Pin], and do
                    self.pins = pins
                 
                    But if I want to be able to return the value or the error, how can I do that?
                 */
            })
            .store(in: &self.subscriptions)
    }
    

    private func _fetchPins(categories: Set<CategoryModel>, coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Future<[Pin], Error> {
        return Future<[Pin], Error> { promise in
            let categoryIds = categories.map { return $0.id }.joined(separator: ",")
            
            let radius = 15 //miles
            
            self.session.request(baseUrl + "/api/v1/pinsRadius?latitude=\(coordinates.latitude)&longitude=\(coordinates.longitude)&radius=\(radius)&categories=\(categoryIds)")
                .responseDecodable(of: [Pin].self) { (response: DataResponse) in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(let pins):
                        promise(.success((pins)))
                    case .failure(let error):
                        promise(.failure(error))
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry if its a dumb question, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use a completion handler in your function and call it from `receiveValue`

```
func fetchPins (categories: Set<CategoryModel>, 
                coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D, 
                completion: @escaping (Result<[Pin], Error>) -> Void))  {
    _fetchPins(categories: categories, coordinates: coordinates)
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
            switch completion {
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(error))
                print("fetchPins() error")
            case .finished:
                print("fetchPins() complete")
            }
        }, receiveValue: { pins in
            completion(.success(pins))
        })
        .store(in: &self.subscriptions)
}
```

Your call to `fetchPins` would then look something like

```
fetchPins(categories: someValue, coordinates: someOtherValue) { pins in
    //do stuff with pins here
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  How can I send the error as well?  I don't have error in the receiveValue block.

Comment: You can change the parameter type for the completion handler from [Instrument] to Result<[Instrument], Error> and then call it either with .success or .failure

Comment: What is the purpose of `.store(in: &self.subscriptions)` if the pins are already stored in the completion: `completion(.success(pins)` ?

Comment: It's the subscription that is stored

Comment: Ok, I see. So it's only needed if you also want to store the subscription besides the pins (in this example)?.

Comment: Also, when you call sink, because the reference to the subscription is stored in the set of AnyCancellable, it will call cancel() on the subscription automatically.  Please correct me if I am wrong, am not expert.